# Is there a flat list of all commands for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, toolbar

I am curious if there is a flat list of **all** commands for Visual Studio?

It would be a nice to have... and to the Tools team at Microsoft, a search/filter box for the "Add Command" window would be nice.

*Specifically, I was wanting to add a toolbar icon to re-show the Start Page in VS2012 to the Standard Toolbar.  And when I got to the "Add Command" window, they are all categorized, and was curious if there was a flat list (here, or on a website) that could just be searched through easily.  I've looked through the similar questions, and am not finding a significant match of either the question, or a useful answer to this question.  Searching online yeilded nearly useless results as well.*

Comment: ReSharper.ReSharper_DumpAllCommands - available in ReSharper 9

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Following answer provided by didito, [full list of VS Commands](https://github.com/aburok/mysettings/blob/master/VisualStudio/vscommands.txt) in plain text.

There's a lot of them, over 4500 :)

I'm 'trying' to use VsVim and I map some of the commands to key combos.

Comment: Unable to load the list.

Comment: @AMissico : strange, the list is available on github.

Comment: Thanks! However, this answer is incomplete without mentioning how to produce this list for my own install of VS. After all, this will vary widely based on version and (probably) configuration of VS.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using VS 2012 you can use the new Quick Launch tool which allows you to search for any menu item, option/preference, command, etc quite easily.  You can read more about it here: [Quick Launch Blog Post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2012/06/26/visual-studio-2012-new-features-quick-launch.aspx)  The screenshot below is the results when you search for Intellitrace:

[image: Quick Launch]

Answer (score 4):

If you go to "Tools/Options/Environment/Keyboard", you will see a listbox containing a ton of the commands in visual studio, as well as a text box with the title "Show commands containing:" that allows you to filter the list of available commands.

Answer (score 2):

Resharper has something called "Resharper - Internal - Dump All VS Commands". I found that via  the Quick Launch tool. Dumps all the commands in a text file, without help or description obviously, but flat. (VS Pro 2012, JetBrains ReSharper 8.2)

Answer (score 1):

Scott Gu has posted a useful list of all keyboard commands available in VS2010. This is available for all dotnet languages.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/visual-studio-2010-keyboard-shortcuts.aspx

Hope this helps.